# Converting Mips loop into C

Tags: c, mips, disassembly

I'm having a lot of trouble converting MIPS to C (I'm very new to it). I've firstly tried to write what is happening next to the MIPS code.

```
blank: addi  $t0, $zero, 0                         t0 = 0;
       addi  $t2, $zero, ' '                       t2 = 32;
       j     L2                                  jump to L2;
L1:    sb    $t2, 0($t1)                         store new value in array
       addi  $t0, $t0, 1                         t0++;
L2:    add   $t1, $a0, $t0                     t1 = a0 + t0;
       lbu   $t3, 0($t1)                         t3 = array(t0)
       bne   $t3, $zero, L1                    if(t3!=0) jump to L1
       jr    $ra                                return; //jump to return address in ra
```

I've have then tried to convert it to C but I'm very confused and I think it is wrong.

```
int array[32];
int i;

for(int i=1; i!=0; i++)
    array[i]=i;

return;
```

If anyone could offer some hints or corrections I would appreciate it greatly

Comment: Won't execute body: `for(int i=0; i!=0; i++)`. Should be `for(int i=0; i<32; i++)`.

Comment: Sorry @FiddlingBits I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: @FiddlingBits: Nope. Look at what `$t2` is used for in the loop. Hint: this is a fill function.

Comment: Why am I getting flagged down, this is a good question

Comment: @Michael do you know what the code is doing

Comment: I don't know MIPS assembly but my guess for the loop is: `for(int i=0; array[i]!=0; i++) array[i]=' ';`

Comment: I do. But I really think that you should be able to figure this out. If you take your annotations and modify them slightly so that you have valid C you can test it by passing a string pointer to the function and inspect the contents of the string afterwards.

Comment: I am trying to figure it out but I simply can't wrap my head around it

Comment: The comments don't look correct.  `addi  $t0, $zero, 0` is `t0 = zero + 0`, where `t0` and `zero` are register alternative names, at least according to http://logos.cs.uic.edu/366/notes/mips%20quick%20tutorial.htm.

Comment: @FiddlingBits I think $zero is a special register which is always the value "0"

Comment: @BarneyChambers You're correct.

Comment: Still can't wrap my head around what's happening here though :P

Comment: How about my code?

Comment: @j_kubik sorry I dont understand the question

Comment: "I don't know MIPS assembly but my guess for the loop is: `for(int i=0; array[i]!=0; i++) array[i]=' ';`" Note that line loading `$t3` for comparison and further assignment use the same value `0($t1)`, so comparison and store apply to the same address.

Comment: @j_kubik I was studying a similar example to my code and the  addi  $t2, $zero, ' ' to me appears to be more of an array size initializer like "int t2[32], as the ascii code for ' ' is 32

Comment: I understand the connection, but I don't think that's what the code says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same code with C-compatible description:

```
                                             void func(char* array){ // possible fuction header
blank: addi  $t0, $zero, 0                         int t0 = 0;
       addi  $t2, $zero, ' '                       char t2 = 32;
       j     L2                                    char* t1;
                                                   goto L2:
L1:    sb    $t2, 0($t1)                           *t1 = t2;
       addi  $t0, $t0, 1                           t0++;
L2:    add   $t1, $a0, $t0                         t1 = &array[t0]; // or t1 = array+t0;
       lbu   $t3, 0($t1)                           char t3 = *t1;
       bne   $t3, $zero, L1                        if(t3!=0) goto L1;
       jr    $ra                                   return;
```

Now it should be clear that ths equates to:

```
void func(char* array){
    for (int i=0; array[i] != 0; ++i)
        array[i] = ' ';
}
```

I might be wrong about the header.

Comment: the proposed code looks good, except for one detail.  I.E. the name of the function is `blank` not `func`.